# What can we use instead of V$parameter in postgresql?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, database-migration

select value
into v_original_nls_date_format
from V$parameter
where upper(name) = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'

Unable to convert system object SYS.V_$PARAMETER? HELP!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pg_settings` as follows:

```
select * from pg_settings where name =  'DateStyle';
```

[Db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=63536d7c9e4c5b92a532955c6acc03bf)

Comment: OP, be warned that `datestyle` is something quite different from the Oracle parameter you are looking for, which does not have a true equivalent in PostgreSQL.